# Rename files in selected folder in Linux

Tags: linux, rename

Command for rename file as IMG0001 to 4R0001 in folder

```
for f in *;do mv "$f" `echo "$f" | sed 's/IMG/4R/g' `; done
```

AND

I just want rename selected folder

```
/tmp/2014/1201 (rename files)
/tmp/2014/1202
.......
/tmp/2014/1220
/tmp/2014/1224 (rename files)
/tmp/2014/1227 
.......
```

find not good for selected folder

awk for selected folder by renamelist.txt but miss match with for loop $value

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The more easy way is use bash substitution in this way:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*IMG*');do mv -v $i ${i//IMG/RG}; done
‘./IMG001.img’ -> ‘./RG001.img’
```

Comment: Quote your variables...

Comment: Thanks, Rename is fine, But I want to rename files by a name list renamelist.txt not all folder

Comment: Gary Lau "find . -type f -name '*IMG*'" in this way find command only works on files.